# php href for user account registration in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

:)

I'm currently editing the customersignin.tpl of my theme and would like to add a 'sign up' link.

Those are the other href classes and href used in the .tpl file:

```
class="logout"
href="{$logout_url}"

class="account"
href="{$my_account_url}"

href="{$my_account_url}"
```

I have no idea what the required class (if needed) and href for the registry form are. I guessed around a little with things like

```
href="{$create_account_url}"
```

But ultimately, I haven't been able to hit it randomly.

Answer (score 0):

To add a sign-up link you can have an idea from the sample code provided with classic theme.

Something like:

```
<a href="{$url_for_register}" data-link-action="display-register-form">
          {l s='No account? Create one here' d='Shop.Theme.Customeraccount'} </a>
```

For PS 1.7.2.4, the authentication template is found in `/themes/classic/templates/customer/authentication.tpl`

https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/themes/classic/templates/customer/authentication.tpl#L40

Comment: `<a class="no-account"
 href="{$url_for_register}" 
 data-link-action="display-register-form"
 title="{l s='No account? Create one here' d='Shop.Theme.Customeraccount'}" 
 >
 <span class="">{l s='Sign up' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}</span>
 </a>`

This is, what I thought it should be based on the template you linked. However, once I click on it on my [website](https://giftify.cc/), it doesn't really link anywhere. - As you'll be able to see if you hover over the link. The other two ones actually link to the right page, whereas 'sign up' doesn't.

Comment: I solved the problem. It changed from %url_for_register to $urls.pages.register